# mpi and process launching/binding

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, schedule

In MPI, is it possible to schedule processes in such a way that one core is mapped to one process, the process finishes and then the core starts working on another process in a situation where the number of processes > number of cores? If so, how exactly is it done? As in, using `mpiexec --bind-to-core -bycore` or using a `hostfile`, `rankfile` etc.

Would really appreciate any input.

Comment: This is supported by most implementations by default. See docs of your implementation for details. The examples you give are similar to what is supported.

Comment: @Jeff oh I thought that they were scheduled in a preemptive round-robin sort of way, with two processes (say) on a core working with context switches, as opposed to a more non-preemptive first-come-first-serve basis. Can you clarify, if possible? And thanks for your help!

Comment: Which implementation are you using?  The MPI standard itself says nothing about how mpiexec works; in fact, it does not even require it exist.

Comment: I'm using `mpiexec (OpenRTE) 1.6.5`. Atleast, that's what it says when I run `mpiexec --version`

Comment: @Jeff can you have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871781/computing-usage-of-independent-cores-and-binding-a-process-to-a-core? Would love to have your input